# How can I reset the data in my services effectively memory-wise - Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, memory, garbage-collection

In my Angular 1.5 app, I often store the data in an object or array so I can use it again in a different service.

```
(function () {
        'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .factory('TemplateList', TemplateList);

    function TemplateList() {
        var templates = {};
    }
})();
```

There are times when I need to clear this data and start fresh over again.

I am not sure which technique of these 3 will be the best in terms of garbage collection and efficiency:

1. templates = {};

Just assign it to be an empty object again.

2. Object.assign(templates, {});
   Use the new ES6 feature to assign it to be an empty object.
3. angular.copy({}, templates) 
   Use the built in angular feature

In addition, what if it is a more complicated case?
For example, I have default data e.g.

```
var defaultData = { name: null, id: null }; 
templates = { name: 'hi', id: 5 }
```

If I do this each time `templates = defaultData` that will not be effective.
Which of the 3 techniques is best in my situation?

Comment: `templates = {}`

You will loose the link with your memory, the GC will found it and then delete the data inside your memory.

Comment: What if it's a little bit more complicated? For example, I have default data e.g. var defaultData = { name: null, id: null }; templates = { name: 'hi', id: 5 } If I do this each time templates = defaultData that will be no good right?

Comment: you just need to loose the reference between your variable and the memory. The GC will use what we call 'mark and sweep' to free your memory.
You will find more things on MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management

Answer (score 0):

`templates = {}` is fine, performance-wise. But you need to be aware that you're creating a new object. If one of your controllers or other services has a reference to the old object, it won't go to garbage collector. Keep the balloon analogy in mind. An object is a balloon and every variable that references that object is a string. Only when all the strings are cut will the balloon float away (to the garbage collector).

`Object.assign()` and `angular.copy()` are incorrect for this task as they will not remove properties from the destination object.

Your final scenario, `templates = defaultData` is also incorrect. It seems you're thinking it will copy `defaultData` onto `templates`, preserving the `defaultData` object. That is not the case. `templates` will simply be a new reference to the same object to which `defaultData` refers. Same balloon, just now two strings.

Here, though, you COULD use `angular.copy()`.

```
templates = angular.copy({}, defaultData);
```

That copies the properties of `defaultData` onto a new anonymous object, which is then assigned to the `templates` variable.